# Magento 2 : Add to cart out of stock products

Tags: magento2

I would like to be able to add to cart products that are Out of Stock. I've already set the

> System --> Configuration --> Catalog --> Inventor --> Backorders =
>   Allow Qty

Below 0 but the add to cart button still not appear.

I tried to write an observer the make the product salable :

```
$salable = $observer->getEvent()->getSalable();
$salable->setIsSalable(true);
```

The add to cart button is displayed but when I add the product to the cart I get the default Magento error: This product is out of stock.

Thanks!

Comment: Where are getting this message in frontend? Because allow qty below 0 you have set for backorders not frontend as Magento default doesn't have this feature for frontend. You need to use preorder extension for this.

Comment: @magentodev plz go to product and make stock status to In Stock then try again.

Comment: Please check your product level setting. you have to try to add configurable product or group or  bundle product,.IN this case parent stock is setting   `Out of Stock`